# can't seem to spot this error in BASH insists that there is a syntax error

Tags: bash

can't find the error here. when i run this program BASH comes up with "[ : 17: unexpected operator" i've tried it with a parameter ending in .c and with one in .java but neither seems to work.

```
EXT=`echo $1 | cut -f2 -d"."`

if [ "$EXT" == "c" ]; then
    NAME=`echo $1 | cut -f1 -d"."`
    gcc -Wall -o "$NAME" "$1"   
elif [ "$EXT" == "java" ]; then
    NAME=`echo $1 | cut -f1 -d"."`
    gcj -c -g -O $1 && gcj --main="$NAME" -o "$NAME" "${NAME}.o"
else    
    echo "hm... I don't seem to know what to do with that"
fi
```

Comment: What's on line 17? Do your arguments (`$1`) contain spaces or other weird characters?

Comment: @honk just test the snippet, it should be line 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test` (aka `[`) doesn't have an `==` operator. String equality is `=` instead. Yes, that's a little bit weird.

Also, `case` is nice for this:

```
case "$1" in
  *.java)
    # java stuff here
    ;;
  *.c)
    # c stuff here
    ;;
  *)
    # otherwise...
esac
```

Comment: thanks. do you know if case is more efficient than if/else? which one runs faster? it won't make a difference here but in general..

Comment: @franklin Shell scripts are not known for their speed. Best to use what is most readable.

Comment: @franklin And any speed difference between if vs. case will be dwarfed by the time it takes to invoke external commands like `gcc` and `gcj`. Shell builtin commands like `if`, `case`, and `echo` are extremely fast compared to external commands which fork new processes.

Comment: That's just not fair (not having a == operator).

Comment: bash built-in `[[ ]]` does have `==`

Answer (score 2):

change all

```
if [ "$EXT" == "c"/"java" ];
```

to

```
if [ "$EXT" = "c"/"java" ];
```